# Tooltips' max-width not working in Firefox 38 but does in Chromium

Tags: html, css, firefox, chromium

I have a input's tooltip that I am trying to set a `max-width`, or basically

> "If the text is smaller than 300px, tooltip width should be the
>   necessary to contain the element. If the text occupies more than
>   300px, line break and contain it."

In this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hrfz442d/11/ it works for Chromium, but in Firefox 38, it doesn't take in account `max-width`, and seems to have a fixed width which it is using.

Firefox JSFiddle:

[image: Firefox]

CSS:

```
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}
.tooltip span {
    position: absolute;
    /*min-width: 100px;*/
    max-width: 150px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #327FBA;
    min-height: 32px;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;

    display: table;
    padding: 0 10px; /* optional */
}
.tooltip span:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 100%;
    margin-top: -8px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-right: 8px solid #327FBA;
    border-top: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
}
.tooltip:hover span {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 0.9;
    left: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -16px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="tooltip">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre/s" name="dp_nombre">
     <span>Nombre completo asd as dasd as dasd</span>
</div>
```

**EDIT: In fact I changed the tooltip's words to be `a a a a` and Firefox is taking the less possible width to contain the words, then line break after each word (letter), so I have 4 lines now.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add width: 100%, and remove display: table (you don't need it).

Comment: Just one exception, if the text is smaller than the max-width, then width will be max-width, not only the necessary to contain the text. I can live with that

Comment: Well, you're saying that it should take 100% of the width, up to the maximum of 150px. And you don't need display: table because, well, it's not a table, and DIVs constrained by their width should wrap the text inside them normally, as expected. :-)

Comment: It's weird, it is still unclear to me why width 100% in case of text `a a a a` takes max-width as width and not only the necessary to contain it. And `width: auto` does not work and breaks at every `a` letter